# How to use Clickhouse with Travis

Tags: docker, travis-ci, clickhouse

I wanna add travis to my repository, i used clickhouse as database, normally i can add postgresql and others like this,

```
services: 
  - postgresql
```

So i searched for clickhouse in documentation of [Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/), but i  couldn't find anything in guide, but it also says

> This guide covers setting up the most popular databases and other
> services in the Travis CI environment.

So are there any workarounds for this or should i run with Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried manually and i found Travis supports clickhouse, the way below worked out for me.

```
services:
  - clickhouse
```